# Creating a new Activity in asp.net core 5

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-5.0

How can I create new `Activity` instances in ASP.NET Core 5?

Do I need to do it from the current source, like so:

```
var activity = Activity.Current?.Source.StartActivity("test");
```

Or can I create my own `ActivitySource` and the activities will auto-magically be created as children of the one created by the framework itself?

Comment: Both. ASP.NET Core generates activities for action requests, so the first option is a good choice there and any new activities will be started under the "parent" activity. In BackgroundServices though you'll need your own activity source, and explicitly use it to create activities. In any case,  whether you need a separate `ActivitySource` or not depends on how you want to trace events. The name of the `ActivitySource` is uses as the source in analyzers and OpenTelemetry tools like Jaeger.

Comment: You can link controller and background activities if you somehow pass an activity's `ActivityContext` from one service to the other. If, for example, you use a controller to queue jobs that are processed by a BackgroundService, you can add the `ActivityContext` to the queued item, retrieve it in the `BackgroundService` and pass it to `StartActivity`. This will make the action request the parent of the job activity